# VBNET Point of Sale Application datagridview

Tags: .net

how can i add up a quantity column in a datagridview 
and also a Total Price column with £ GBP currency, both are getting displayed as label.text

also how can I times the quantity column with the unit price column. this gives me the total price column figure

also where would i put the code because i have tried an example code but didn't work i want the item count and total price to change as the barcode is scanned and entered(so when the datagridview shows the result)

Thanks

Forgot to mention I'm a total beginner.

Comment: Carl, can you post some of the code you've tried?  Try to keep your code sample simple, so that it represents what you're trying to do without too much extra.